# Perl + Append text from file1 to the end of every line of file2 in command line

Tags: perl, merge, text-files

I can not manage to achieve this thing with Perl using command line only, even if I fill that it has to be very easy. I should only read file IDAT0100F that has one line only and append it to the end of every line of file IDAT0300F, producing the result in file IDAT0300F.out. I would like to execute the command for more files that have different width and number of record (IDAT0100F remains the same). Thanks in advance!

```
FILE: IDAT0100F (without the extension)
201302201212120

FILE: IDAT0300F (without the extension)
000164198506DTCV0
000164198506DTDP0
000164198506DTMO0
000164198506DTPR0
000164198506DTTR0

RESULT: IDAT0300F.out
000164198506DTCV0201302201212120
000164198506DTDP0201302201212120
000164198506DTMO0201302201212120
000164198506DTPR0201302201212120
000164198506DTTR0201302201212120
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a simple one-liner.

```
perl -plwe 'BEGIN { $\=<> }' ida1.txt ida2.txt > ida.out
```

Assuming the first file contains the header, and only contains one line. This will read one line from the first file, and assign that line to the output record separator `$\`, aka the thing that gets appended to the end of every print statement. This will work in combination with the `-l` switch, which will remove newline from lines read *after* the BEGIN block is executed.

If the first file contains more lines, you can explicitly close the file to prevent more lines being read from it:

```
perl -plwe 'BEGIN { $\=<>; close ARGV; }' ida1.txt ida2.txt > ida.out
```

The full code of this one-liner is (edited for brevity from deparsed version):

```
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "201302201212120\n"; }
sub BEGIN {
    $\ = <>;
    close ARGV;
}
while (<>) {
    chomp $_;
}
continue {
    print $_;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I tried to get accomplished! What would be the code if non of the files have headers and that one with the date have one line only? ))